# Dynamic height on sticky header

Tags: css, angular, dom, angular-directive, sticky

I'm having troubles with the offset of a dynamic sticky header (I mean, the height of the header is variable) and also a sticky sidebar.

Here is an example of the layout:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-z9g5ma

I've created a directive to dynamically calculate the height of this header and then apply it to the height of the sidebar. Something is going wrong tho...

Answer (score 0):

Though you done almost all the things right but you have added a stick-top class to the tag aside. Removing which solves the problem which is created due to the z-index being same for two elements & aside taking the priority.
Would suggest to go through the code and debug the same in the browser for not committing such mistakes.

```
    <aside class="col-4 bg-light sticky-top" [fluidHeight]>
```

Remove the sticky-top class from here.

Comment: But I want the sidebar also sticky. Similar to the left sidebar of StackOverflow, while the main content scrolling.

Comment: Then add `style="top: 8vh;"` to the tag `<aside class="col-4 bg-light sticky-top" [fluidHeight]>`. Use media query if you feel to change the top margin according to devices

Comment: Why `8vh`? The point is that the header has dynamic height depending on the content itself.

Comment: Yep you can do similar thing or else put top equals some value according to the screen size using media queries. The thing with the header is top is 0 which means it should attach/stick to the top of the screen whereas in the case of you aside you should have some top margin that's why I had put 8vh. If you put top:0 for this also it will come over the header and that's where you are facing issue